Can't find a working syntax for jsdom.getElementById in typescript
Using the following code snippet I've tried a variety of search strings like the following list but so far getElementById() always returns undefined.  What am I doing wrong?
'//h1'
'h1'
'title'
'//title'
'body'
'Hello'
etc
Output from the following code is always
elem=null
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
const htmlContent = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Hello World Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World Body</h1>
</body>
</html>`;
// verify the starting text is OK
console.log(`htmlContent=${htmlContent.substring(50, 200)}`);

const dom = new JSDOM(htmlContent);
const doc = dom.window.document;
const elem = doc.getElementById("//title");
console.log(`      elem=${elem}`);


doc.querySelector('title') instead.

You're confusing CSS selector and XPath syntax. Use the former, not the latter.

This question is similar to: How to get the title of HTML page with JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are using doc.getElementById to get the value from tag <title>. This is incorrect as <title> is a tag in the DOM.
You should use getElementsByTagName("title");
const elem = doc.getElementsByTagName("//title")[0];

Alternatively assign an id to your <title>.
For example,  <title id="title1">Hello World Title</title>.
Then you should able to get the value with const elem = doc.getElementById("//title1");

Thx. Getting the names right is important. Especially when error messages misdirect you. I had tried getElementByTag and the compiler spit out:
Property 'getElementByTag' does not exist on type 'Document'. Did you mean 'getElementById'?

... NO, I meant getElementByTagName!
Cheers!

This doesn't work. // is xpath. doc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]; is the correct CSS selector syntax, but doc.querySelector("title") is cleaner. Or doc.title if OP just wants the string.

You need to put an ID to the element if you want to getElementById.

Why not show the actual code?
